# Xcode error when attempting to archive project: Unexpected duplicate tasks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, archive

My project runs totally fine with no warnings on both the simulator and a real device, but when I try to archive it, I get this error:

> Unexpected duplicate tasks:
>
> > 1) Target 'SwiftDataTables' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/myAppPath/Pods/SwiftDataTables/SwiftDataTables/SwiftDataTables.bundle/column-sort-descending.png' to '/Users/Marius/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myAppName-bvaclcqghnevllgdezgzmpfvrzrz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myAppName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/SwiftDataTables.framework/column-sort-descending.png'
> >
> > 2) Target 'SwiftDataTables' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/myAppPath/Pods/SwiftDataTables/SwiftDataTables/SwiftDataTables.bundle/column-sort-descending.png' to '/Users/Marius/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myAppName-bvaclcqghnevllgdezgzmpfvrzrz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myAppName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/SwiftDataTables.framework/column-sort-descending.png'

I get this error 3 times, one for each of the pictures that are in the **SwiftDataTables**.

I have already tried cleaning the project, uninstalling and reinstalling the problematic library, and removing all the files from Derived Data. From what I have seen from other similar questions, the solution is often checking that a file isn't listed both in **Copy Bundle Resources** and **Compile Sources** in target/Build phases, but I can't find any file that is listed twice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I could fix it by selecting the three images in Xcode and then remove the Target Membership for SwiftDataTables and adding it again.

[image: Untick and tick target membership in Xcode]

Answer (score 0):

> **Try again** - In the file navigator you can try searching (Cmd+F) to see
>   if the files are somehow in the project twice. Try removing entire
>   framework and any references from the file navigator and the build
>   settings (check under Frameworks folder, et al), and then re-add. Check the pods files listed in the build
>   settings. There is a place where the file paths are added for example
>   if you tried using Carthage previously where the duplication is
>   occurring.

Comment: I have the same problem like Marsolgen, to resolve it you have to delete 3 files in Pods/SwiftTables, because the 3 files are also in the folder Resources.

For me work 100%